# MySQL function with UPDATE after SELECT using RETURN variable

Tags: mysql, function, procedure

I'm trying to update a column in a row after I select that row using a function in MySQL so this can happen in one transaction.

I created the function with no errors and can run the function just fine while it returns a record but I am noticing it's not running the UPDATE query using the returned variable.

I have confirmed the UPDATE query works when running it alone.

Here is my CREATE FUNCTION script:

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION `cc_jqual_update`(
    `cause_location` VARCHAR(30)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE cause_number VARCHAR(20);
select court_cases.cause_no INTO cause_number
  from court_cases
  where ((court_cases.cause_loc = cause_location)
   and (court_cases.cause_status not in ('Dismissed','Disposed'))) LIMIT 1;
RETURN cause_number;
update court_cases set last_read = now() where cause_no = cause_number;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Might be your logical ordering of the RETURN and UPDATE. Try swapping the two statements?

Comment: The `RETURN` will stop the execution. It always should be the last thing you do in a function.

Comment: But wouldn't the update query need the script to return the variable first so it can be used in the update?

Comment: No. It just needs the variable. But why are you updating in a function? A function should usually just return data, not make changes.

Comment: The caller of the function should then do the update with the returned value.

Comment: `UPDATE court_cases SET last_read = now() WHERE cause_number = cc_jqual_update()`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a stored procedure for CRUD operations.  Use a SELECT statement for an output value.